# Unable to login with Local account (user) after joining onto domain

Tags: users

I am trying to login with local pc account with user level access but denied saying "you cannot log on because the logon methods you are using is not allowed on this computer".

But when I am adding that local account into power user group in local machine, it allow to login.

Please suggest how to be into local user group only and login into domain joined machine.

Comment: Are you trying to log on remotely?

Comment: It sounds to me like there's a Group Policy preventing members in the local Users group from logging on locally. You'll need to investigate and change that.